# Jquery, how I can call the same function without rewrite

Tags: javascript, jquery

usually when I need to use the same function with some edits I must copy/paste the function and then add some variables (sometimes the code is very long)

for example:
1st f unction

```
                $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: url,
                data: {s: size},
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                //data
```

In the second function i have to add a variable in data (success data will be the same as the first function):

```
                $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: url,
                data: {s: size, f:from},
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                //data
```

How I can call the first function without rewrite all?

Comment: You could put the AJAX call in its own function and pass the data object as a parameter.

Answer (score 2):

You can have an function and pass the data into it and call your `$ajax` inside the function with the given `data`. Also you can pass your callbacks into it to make more flexible.

```
function makeAjax(data, success, error){
   $.ajax({
          type: 'GET',
          url: url,
          data: data,
          dataType: 'json',
          success: success,
          error: error
       });
}
```

Comment: Again, please close obvious duplicates as such, instead of answering them.

Answer (score 0):

Enclose your AJAX request in a single function and pass your data as a parameter.

```
function ajax_request(request_data) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: url,
        data: request_data,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
             //do something here
        }
    });
}
```